# Get body of MultipartFormDataInput in background thread

Tags: java, wildfly, resteasy

I have a possibly large file to parse, passed to REST service as a part of `MultipartFormDataInput`. As parsing may take a long time, I want to do it in a background thread:

```
@Resource
private ManagedExecutorService executorService;

@POST
@Path("file")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public void upload(MultipartFormDataInput input) {
    executorService.execute(() -> {
        for (InputPart inputPart : input.getFormDataMap().get("file")) {
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = inputPart.getBody(InputStream.class, null);
                CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
                // further processing
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Something went wrong", e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Unfortunately, `getBody` throws following error:

org.jboss.resteasy.spi.LoggableFailure: RESTEASY003880: **Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers**

Any chance I can extract body within a different thread?

Full stacktrace below:

```
16:33:30,634 ERROR [MyService] (EE-ManagedExecutorService-default-Thread-4) Something went wrong: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.LoggableFailure: RESTEASY003880: Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ContextParameterInjector$GenericDelegatingProxy.invoke(ContextParameterInjector.java:75)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.getMessageBodyReader(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartInputImpl$PartImpl.getBody(MultipartInputImpl.java:335)
    at MyService.lambda$upload$0(MyService.java:189)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ControlPointUtils$ControlledRunnable.run(ControlPointUtils.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAsConsumer(SecurityIdentity.java:335)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsConsumer(Scoped.java:101)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:49)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.SecurityIdentityUtils.lambda$doIdentityWrap$1(SecurityIdentityUtils.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.concurrent.internal.ManagedFutureTask.run(ManagedFutureTask.java:141)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThread.run(ManagedThreadFactoryImpl.java:250)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.service.ElytronManagedThreadFactory$ElytronManagedThread.lambda$run$0(ElytronManagedThreadFactory.java:76)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAsConsumer(SecurityIdentity.java:335)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsConsumer(Scoped.java:101)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:49)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.service.ElytronManagedThreadFactory$ElytronManagedThread.run(ElytronManagedThreadFactory.java:76)
```

Comment: And what is the request-handling thread assigned to the request going to be doing while your background thread is processing the form data?  It's not clear to me that doing the parsing in a background thread would gain you anything at all.

Comment: As shown in provided code - it quits (returns to pool hopefully) immediately.

Comment: But that's the point, @Artur: it *must not* "quit" until the request it has been assigned to has been fully processed.  Even in the somewhat doubtful case that if you can formulate an appropriate response without having parsed the form data, you cannot continue to use the request object, directly or indirectly, after the request-handling thread finishes with the request.

Comment: It is conceivable that "fully processing" the request could mean extracting all the needed data from it and queueing it to some background processor, but then what do you do if the data are incomplete or erroneous, or if processing fails for some other reason?  In your scenario, you can't communicate any such thing via the response.

Comment: It's not the case of "quitting" of the request-handling thread - waiting doesn't help. I know that I can "fully process" all of input data before passing to the background, but I don't want to. Is a requirement of "fully processing" some kind of a standard?

Comment: One key constraint here is this: "you cannot continue to use the request object, directly or indirectly, after the request-handling thread finishes with the request."  This is indeed a provision of the Java EE specifications.  Although your handler does not use the request object directly, it's where the form data reside.  Your `MultipartFormDataInput` relies on it.

Comment: That's not necessarily the *only* problem, however.  The immediate issue is probably that your processing depends on dependency injection, and once the processing is pushed into a different thread, there is no longer an appropriate context to inform correct dependency injection.  So to expand my earlier assertion, it may be possible to extract the needed data from the request and queue it for background processing, but the background processing cannot rely on the request, *or on anything else provided contextually to the request-processing thread*.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I know how to solve the problem and I know it is connected to injection of some dependencies in a background thread. What I am asking for is either a correct method of processing input data in another thread, or a documentation reference that states it is not possible (I haven't found it so far).